# Cannot set up local server using external IP

Tags: python, network-programming

I'm trying to set up two servers on my laptop using the script in https://github.com/misheska/foundations-of-python-network-programming/blob/master/python2/02/udp_remote.py.

As far as I understand, I can set a server just by typing

```
$ python udp_remote.py server
```

I want to start another server using my external IP, that I get using:

```
$ wget -q -O - http://myexternalip.com/raw
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

Then the server should be set with

```
$  python udp_remote.py server XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

right???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is correct (other than your IP4s being only 3 bytes long), but there are a couple reasons why you're having trouble:

1. It's not possible to bind to the same port twice on the same interface. Because the script has a fixed port number, you won't be able to run more than one instance unless your laptop has multiple interfaces.
2. Your WAN IP address will only be resolvable to an interface if your laptop itself is actually assigned that address. If the laptop is connected to a router and is assigned a local address, you won't be able to use the WAN address to specify the interface.

Comment: is there a way to workaround this? I imagine it should be something like to trick the OS. Ok talk to the machine XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX that's actually the local one, but through the router....
Maybe the point is to set the 127.0.0.0 only to the OS-network, and that this is separated from the external IP, right?

Comment: No, the specified address is a listening address, not a destination address, and that gets translated to a specific interface. Adding a virtual interface at the OS level will give you a second interface to bind to. But to use the WAN IP you will need to use forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind to an IP address that is not bound to an interface on the computer. If you require port forwarding to be set up on a router then consult your network administrator.